# How to get Cucumber to work as a integration_tool generator?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I have the following settings

```
Rails.application.config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec, 
                   :fixture => true
  g.integration_tool :cucumber
  g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, :dir => "spec/factories"
end
```

And yet when I try to run:

```
rails g inherited_resources_controller gallery name:string publish_at:time
```

I get a:

```
error    cucumber [not found]
```

However, I googled the issue and it seems a lot of people are using this setting without a problem.
Any ideas why it's not working for me? Using Rails 3.0.6 (just updated to 3.0.7) and the latest version of cucumber.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is `cucumber` included in the output of `rails g`?

Comment: Yes, you can do rails g cucumber:install or rails g cucumber:feature

Comment: Where did you put Cucumber in your Gemfile? Is it inside the development group?

Comment: I've put cucumber-rails in both my development and test groups - do I also need to put cucumber in there as well? Just tried this and still got the same error. I am using Rails 3.1.0.rc5 and Cucumber 1.0.2